# Apply ng-style after element is created with jquery

Tags: angularjs, codemirror

I use [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) and angular.
*CodeMirror* element is created dynamically by calling

```
myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea( document.getElementById("paper"), opts );
```

This line creates a .CodeMirror div after textarea#paper.

Question is how do I apply ng-style directive to **div.CodeMirror** which is created after calling **fromTextArea** function?

The reason of it that I have to style exatly this dom element, not any other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that manually with the jquery plugin, you'll need to `$compile` your generated HTML :

```
  var html = '<div ng-bind="exp"></div>';

  // Step 1: parse HTML into DOM element
  var template = angular.element(html);

  // Step 2: compile the template
  var linkFn = $compile(template);

  // Step 3: link the compiled template with the scope.
  var element = linkFn(scope);

  // Step 4: Append to DOM (optional)
  parent.appendChild(element);
```

Some information + example source here : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler

But you should definitely use a dedicated angularJS solution like http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-codemirror/

When using a jquery plugin (which modify DOM) you should really search its angularJS equivalent or you'll gonna have some serious probleme (like you're having)

Hope this helps